# Extracting text from Hadoop RCfile Gzip with Apache Tika

Tags: hadoop, apache-tika

I'm using Apache Tika to extract text from an Apache Hadoop RCfile sample file I created (using Hadoop's GZip compression), and it appears that the Tika's mime-type detection is not working correctly for this file. Any ideas how I can build support (via XML config, or building a detector) to parse this format correctly?

```
java -jar tika-app-1.14.jar /dev/sample_data/sample_gen_hadoop_rcfile
```

Returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="X-Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser"/>
<meta name="resourceName" content="sample_gen_hadoop_rcfile"/>
<meta name="Content-Length" content="20224466"/>
<meta name="Content-Type" content="application/octet-stream"/>
<title/>
</head>
```

The RCfile I created is in gzip format- hex dump below

```
   :sample_data $ xxd sample_gen_hadoop_rcfile |head -n 50
    00000000: 5243 4601 0127 6f72 672e 6170 6163 6865  RCF..'org.apache
    00000010: 2e68 6164 6f6f 702e 696f 2e63 6f6d 7072  .hadoop.io.compr
    00000020: 6573 732e 477a 6970 436f 6465 6300 0000  ess.GzipCodec...
    00000030: 011c 6869 7665 2e69 6f2e 7263 6669 6c65  ..hive.io.rcfile
    00000040: 2e63 6f6c 756d 6e2e 6e75 6d62 6572 0231  .column.number.1
```

Comment: Did you try following http://tika.apache.org/1.14/parser_guide.html ?

Comment: @Gagravarr I did read the parser guide. I'm surprised as Tika (and the file command, for that matter) do not seem to be able to extract the correct MIME type from this file (resolving as application/octet-stream) which would be the first step towards sending to the correct decoder

Comment: Mime detection shouldn't be too hard, there looks to be quite a simple but unique pattern at the start. Any idea what the mimetype should be for this file, eg from the Apache Hadoop or Apache Hive documentation?